# Multiplicity is not valid in Role '. the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is the model one to many(Applicant). The(AttachedDocument) is many model I think I have the relations wrong

```
public partial class Applicant
{
    [Key]
    public int ApplicantID { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationSource { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicantID")]
    public virtual ICollection<AttachedDocuments> AttachedDocuments { get; set; }

}


public partial class AttachedDocuments
{
    [Key]
    public int AttachedDocID { get; set; }
    public int ApplicantID { get; set; }
    public string AttechedDocGUID { get; set; }
    public int DocumentTypeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicantID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Applicant> Applicant { get; set; }
}
```

And here the builder:

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>().HasRequired(a => a.AttachedDocuments).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.ApplicantID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AttachedDocuments>().HasOptional(b => b.Applicant).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b => b.ApplicantID);
    }
```

First time doing model with relations. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the foreign key attribute from your applicant class? The ForeignKey attribute specifies the name of the property which will be the foreign key. You're specifying the name of the Key property which would cause a database to flip out.

```
public partial class Applicant
{
    [Key]
    public int ApplicantID { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationSource { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AttachedDocuments> AttachedDocuments { get; set; }

}


public partial class AttachedDocuments
{
    [Key]
    public int AttachedDocID { get; set; }
    public string AttachedDocGUID { get; set; }
    public int DocumentTypeID { get; set; }

    public int ApplicantID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicantID")]
    public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
}
```